# Is it a problem that I am never considered for new opportunities at work?

Tags: management, work-environment, ethics, team, software-development

I have worked for a private firm for the last 9 months. I find myself facing the below problems everyday:

1. My ex-manager who resigned recently, did not convey a good image of me to the Executive Team. There are two developers in our team and my manager always supported the other developer for everything. She never respected/appreciated me for any of my work, rather she always complained and yelled at me in front of others. When she left the company, she did not give any positive opinion about me to the Executive Management. So I feel I am not being considered for any team tasks or I am being considered as 'Not-so-potential' candidate by the Management team.
2. The Executive team is hiring 2 new people for our team and they want
   the Other developer to do knowledge transfer to the new people while
   that other developer is so busy and going out for 1 month vacation.
   The Executive Team never considered me to interview new
   candidates/train them but they reached out to other team heads to do
   so. This is bothering me as why I am not  being considered for
   anything.
3. Since we are working on multiple projects, I am never offered any complex projects rather given with very simple ones. They still feel I am not experienced to handle projects with compressed deadlines even though I proved them my ability in many aspects

Question:

1. Do these actions symbolize something? Or should I infer
   something from all these happenings? Should I consider that the
   Executive Team is going against me based on my ex-manager's viewpoint?
2. Because they are hiring 2 new people even through they need only 1
       person to support the team, will it have any effect on my role?

I'm confused. Any help?

Comment: Have you asked your current manager or executive management about these things?

Comment: No. Since the Ex-Manager went, we don't have a Manager for now and we are supervised directly by the Executive team

Comment: How long has the other developer been with the company?

Comment: I get that they haven't asked you to do more but how do you know they have not considered asking you to do more?

Comment: I'm sure there is information missing here, either that or you're a bad fit for the company

Answer (score 3):

At this point your only real option is to **talk to members of the executive team** and *ask them*.  Have your questions straight in your mind, and request a meeting with them to discuss.

Based on what the executives do **or don't** say you can then at least attempt to plan your next course of action. ( *Basically decide if you're going to stay or move on* )

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Do these actions symbolize something? Or should I infer something from
>   all these happenings? Should I consider that the Executive Team is
>   going against me based on my ex-manager's viewpoint?

Certainly not being considered for important tasks is a bad sign.

But why they are doing it is something only you are in a position to know. It could be that your ex-manager badmouthed you, and the Executive Team is reacting solely to that. Or it could be that the Executive Team knows you well enough and just doesn't think you are capable.

> Because they are hiring 2 new people even through they need only 1
>   person to support the team, will it have any effect on my role?

Again, only you are in a position to make an educated guess.

It could be that the Executive Team thinks it takes more than one person to support the team now. Or it could be that you will be canned and replaced by one of the newbies.

Time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yelling at an employee under ones supervision is unprofessional and unacceptable behavior, bordering on bullying (especially if done in front of colleagues.

You should have voiced your concerns against this to your manager, HR and the executive team (lesson for the future).

I go out on a limb here and say you didn't provoke those incidents by refusing to follow instructions or guidelines.

However, even if she had valid critique points regarding your work or behavior, yelling is not a professional reaction, unless to prevent an immediate incident or accident with damage to property or cause of bodily harm.

Regarding your questions:

It shows that your superiors may regard you as an employee lacking abilities in communication / social interaction and / or professional expertise.
If you show no considerable improvement in those fields, you might be let go sooner or later. 
If the new hires mean your total team size will be extended, it can signal more work is coming in or that indeed they may plan on replacing you.
Assert yourself, become more proactive and communicate with the executive team about your concerns.
You may mention a few examples of your ex-managers behavior and why you think they now may perceive you to be less capable than you are but emphasize / guide their focus towards your willingness to prove otherwise.

It might be too late but it's certainly better than keeping your head down / sticking with business as usual.